Is it illegal (in the US) to offer financial incentives that require a registration to vote?
According to himself and various news sources, the owner of Twitter/X, Elon Musk, is seeking support to a petition called "Petition in Favor of Free Speech and the Right to Bear Arms" aka "America PAC". A payment of $47 is offered to anyone that refers a registered voter who then goes on to sign the petition. In the case of the state of Pennsylvania, one receives $100 per such reference instead of $47, and everybody that signs the petition receives $100, too.
Additionally, a one million dollar is offered each day by random draw to those that signed the petition. Apart from the slightly different monetary incentive in PA, this offer is said to be valid in the so-called swing states or states that will likely determine the outcome of the upcoming US election under the current electoral system: Arizona, Georgia, Michigan, Nevada, North Carolina, Pennsylvania and Wisconsin and is valid until November 5th 2024.
Is this legal or illegal? Specifically, is it legal to limit recipients of $100 and the chance to win $1M to registered voters?
Edit: I deleted the lower part of my question after being advised that I'm asking too many questions at once. I hope it's more focused now.

Paying someone to register to vote would appear to be illegal, under 52 USC 10307(c):

(c) False information in registering or voting; penalties
Whoever knowingly or willfully gives false information as to his name, address or period of residence in the voting district for the
purpose of establishing his eligibility to register or vote, or
conspires with another individual for the purpose of encouraging his
false registration to vote or illegal voting, or pays or offers to
pay or accepts payment either for registration to vote or for voting
shall be fined not more than $10,000 or imprisoned not more than five years, or both: Provided, however, That this provision shall be
applicable only to general, special, or primary elections held solely
or in part for the purpose of selecting or electing any candidate for
the office of President, Vice President, presidential elector, Member
of the United States Senate, Member of the United States House of
Representatives, Delegate from the District of Columbia, Guam, or the
Virgin Islands, or Resident Commissioner of the Commonwealth of Puerto
Rico.

It is unclear whether paying someone to sign a petition or participate in a lottery, which happens to require that you be already a registered voter, is the same as paying someone to register to vote.

It may be illegal, although AFAIK there's no decisive court review precedent yet.
The two statutes in question are 18 USC 597 and 18 USC 600. The first forbids payments for voting/not voting, and the second forbids payments for political activity.
Conditioning participation in raffle on being registered voter may be running afoul of the first one, while conditioning participation in raffle on signing a political petition may be running afoul of the second one. The DOJ has previously determined that past political activity is not a relevant consideration for the purposes of 18 USC 600, but in this case the condition is forward looking (i.e.: people who signed on to the petition or registered to vote after the announcement are eligible to participate, and in fact it can be argued that the raffle is intended to encourage exactly that).
Discussing more may be more suitable for politics@SE, since it would be pure speculation. There's enough of that in the news.

This seems like a non-answer. As I read it, OP is likely asking the question because they are already aware that this conduct "may be running afoul" of the law. It would be helpful to edit the answer to reach a conclusion, or at least explain what other information would be necessary to do so.

@bdb484 given that this has not yet reached the courts, I can't think of a way to provide a better answer. But I'm sure you have a better crystal ball, so why don't you write yours? The OP has shown no indication that they know the answer to their question, I don't know why you think it's likely.

No, I didn't mean to suggest OP knows the answer to the question, just that OP already knows what's in your answer to the question, i.e., that this conduct may or may not be illegal.

Well yes, obviously, it's all over the news. The way I read it was "why is it illegal, if it is", which is what I tried to address. I provided the specific code sections involved, and explained how they may be applied here. Whether or not the courts agree with my interpretation - we'll have to wait and see, unless you're aware of any precedent other than the only one I could find.

Wasn't there a SCOTUS ruling that a payment isn't a bribe if it's paid after the politician takes the action in question? It's possible this could be treated similarly.

@Barmar yes, as I said the DOJ position since the 1980s was that rewarding political activity after the fact is not covered by that statute. But I don't know wether Musk limits participation in his raffle with a cut off date of the announcement, and if he doesn't that analysis would not apply.

@Barmar if the timing of the payment were decisive then every bribe would be paid after the fact.  Surely the existence of an agreement or understanding before the fact would be more important than the payment being made after the fact.

@phoog I read the decision a few months ago, but found it confusing and I might be mischaracterizing it somewhat.

@Barmar was it Snyder v. US?  I haven't read it yet, but it seems to match your description.  One aspect that stands out is that it concerns the application of the federal law to state and local officials.

@phoog Yes. Wikipedia summarizes it as "prohibits bribes to state and local officials but does not make it a crime for those officials to accept gratuities for their past acts." Basically, if you didn't discuss it with the official first, it's not a bribe. The loophole is that it might be common knowledge that you'll get that gratuity (like the way a waiter knows they'll get a tip).
